# DB Index speed vs caching

Tags: performance, oracle, caching, indexing

We have about 10K rows in a table.  We want to have a form where we have a select drop down that contains distinct values of a given column in this table.  We have an index on the column in question.

To increase performance I created a little cache table that contains the distinct values so we didn't need to do a `select distinct field from table` against 10K rows.  Surprisingly it seems doing `select * from cachetable` (10 rows) is no faster than doing the select distinct against 10K rows.  Why is this?  Is the index doing all the work?  At what number of rows in our main table will there be a performance improvement by querying the cache table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a DB, 10K rows is *nothing*. You're not seeing much difference because the actual calculation time is minimal, with most of it consumed by other, constant, overhead.

It's difficult to predict when you'd start noticing a difference, but it would probably be at around a million rows.

If you've already set up caching and it's not detrimental, you may as well leave it in.

Answer (score 4):

10k rows is not much... start caring when you reach 500k ~ 1 million rows.

Indexes do a great job, specially if you just have 10 different values for that index.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on numerous factors - the amount of memory your DB has, the size of the rows in the table, use of a parameterised query and so forth, but generally 10K is not a lot of rows and particularly if the table is well indexed then it's not going to cause any modern RDBMS any sweat at all.

As a rule of thumb I would generally only start paying close attention to performance issues on a table when it passes the 100K rows mark, and 500K doesn't usually cause much of a problem if indexed correctly and accessed by such.  Performance usually tends to fall off catastrophically on large tables - you may be fine on 500K rows but crawling on 600K - but you have a long way to go before you are at all likely to hit such problems.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the index doing all the work?

You can  tell how the query is being executed by viewing the execution plan.

For example, try this:

```
explain plan for select distinct field from table;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

I notice that you didn't include an ORDER BY on that. If you do not include ORDER BY then the order of the result set may be random, particularly if oracle uses the HASH algorithm for making a distinct list. You ought to check that.

So I'd look at the execution plans for the original query that you think is using an index, and at the one based on the cache table. Maybe post them and we can comment on what's really going on.

Incidentaly, the cache table would usually be implemented as a materialised view, particularly if the master table is generally pretty static.

Answer (score 2):

Serious premature optimization. Just let the database do its job, maybe with some tweaking to the configuration (especially if it's MySQL, which has several cache types and settings).

Answer (score 1):

Your query in `10K` rows most probably uses `HASH SORT UNIQUE`.

As `10K` most probably fit into `db_buffers` and `hash_area_size`, all operations are performed in memory, and you won't note any difference.

But if the query will be used as a part of a more complex query, or will be swapped out by other data, you may need `disk I/O` to access the data, which will slow your query down.

Run your query in a loop in several sessions (as many sessions as there will be users connected), and see how it performs in that case.

Answer (score 0):

For future plans and for scalability, you may want to look into an indexing service that uses pure memory or something faster than the TCP DB round-trip.  A lot of people (including myself) use Lucene to achieve this by normalizing the data into flat files.

Lucene has a built-in Ram Drive directory indexer, which can build the index all in memory - removing the dependency on the file system, and greatly increasing speed.

Lately, I've architected systems that have a single Ram drive index wrapped by a Webservice.  Then, I have my Ajax-like dropdowns query into that Webservice for high availability and high speed - no db layer, no file system, just pure memory and if remote tcp packet speed.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an index on the column, then all the values are in the index and the dbms never has to look in the table. It just looks in the index which just has 10 entries. If this is  mostly read only data, then cache it in memory.  Caching helps scalability and a lot by relieving the database of work.  A query that is quick on a database with no users, might perform poorly if a 30 queries are going on at the same time.

Comment: -1: A b-tree index doesn't have ten entries -- it has one entry for every non-null row, and each entry includes the rowid.